# Can't bind DataTable to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys I've just started programming and I'm running into a problem. The new Datatable i created doesnt show in GridView2 when button1 is clicked. Although it is filled with data from the "planning" table(checked that dtPlanning is filled with the TextBoxes in comment).

So in short: I want to get DataTable planning into the new DataTable dtPlanning and display it in a gridview.

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtPlanning = new DataTable();
    dtPlanning.Columns.Add("Courseday", typeof(int));
    dtPlanning.Columns.Add("Part", typeof(string));
    dtPlanning.Columns.Add("Design", typeof(string));
    dtPlanning.Columns.Add("Lesson", typeof(string));

    //DataRow dr = planning.Rows[1];  
    //TextBox2.Text = (dr["Daynumber"]).ToString();
    //TextBox3.Text = (dr["Part"]).ToString();
    //TextBox4.Text = (dr["Design"]).ToString();
    //TextBox5.Text = (dr["Lesson"]).ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < dtPlanning.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtPlanning.NewRow();
        foreach (DataRow datarow in planning.Rows)
        {
            dtPlanning.Rows.Add(datarow);
        }
    }
    GridView2.DataSource = dtPlanning;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

**Source code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: dtPlanning is empty except this is not all your code

Comment: Check planning.Rows count and Data

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, `dtPlanning.Rows.Count = 0` because this table is just initialized!
Secondly, you cannot `Add` a row from one table to another, user `Import`

```
for (int i = 0; i < planning.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dtPlanning.ImportRow(planning.Rows[i]);
}
```

I wonder why don't you just use the table `planning`?

Comment: Because I want to add more rows and checkfunctions to create a completly new table. I only use the information inside the planning table.

Answer (score 0):

You must:

1. Add to DataSet a new DataTable
2. Add to DataTable a new Columns
3. And GridView2.DataSource=YourNameDataSet.Tables[index_of_DataTable_in_DataSet].DefaultView;